# Internet connection slows down on second router - router to router without bridge mode

Tags: networking, connection, fiber, bridge-router

I recently upgraded my fiber connection from Vodafone to 1Gbit/s down and 200Mbit/s up. Unfortunately, the new ONT gateway with integrated WLAN does not support bridge mode on any of the 4 GE ports and Vodafone is unwilling to do anything about this.

I connected the WAN port of my ASUS router on port 4 on the ONT and switched off the DHCP and WLAN of the Vodafone's ONT.

**When I connect directly to an ethernet port of the ONT I am getting the full speed (~950Mbit/s down and ~195Mbit/s up) but if I connect through the ASUS router I am getting a max of 30Mbit/s up and down...**

Is this normal because the ONT does not support bridge mode? 
Is there anything I can do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) What speed does the Asus ethernet support? (2) It's possible to reconfigure your Asus router as a simple switch, if not with the ASUS firmware, then with open source firmware like OpenWRT. In that case, you should get the maximum speed of the Asus ethernet ports, whatever it is.This will be the same as "bridged mode".

Comment: @dirkt It supports 1000Mbit/s full-duplex.

Comment: @dirkt If I configure the Asus router as a switch router then I would lose the firewall/vpn/nat functions which I would like to keep if it is possible.